# Sync Gradle projects with workspace failed

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle to import JDA into my project, and I have been having major problems all day with it. Both IntelliJ and Eclipse are fighting against me and I am not sure why. I tried to refresh my gradle project to try and get it to sync with my workspace, but the following error occurred:

```css
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.

A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe'
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\luckycosmos\.gradle\daemon\4.3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invokeRun(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:170)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invoke(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:160)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$1.get(DefaultModelProvider.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$3.call(DefaultModelProvider.java:142)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
 at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:153)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:138)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeBuildActionExecuter(DefaultModelProvider.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModels(DefaultModelProvider.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.fetchEclipseProjects(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:91)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'
 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:222)
 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:202)
 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:342)
 at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:35)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe'
 at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
 at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
 at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
 at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\luckycosmos\.gradle\daemon\4.3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
 ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
 ... 12 more
```

Now as far as I can tell, it can't run the JRE which I have uninstalled and reinstalled about 4 times tonight because of the errors I have been getting. I have JDK and JRE 1.8 installed.

Here is my build.gradle:

```css
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:3.6.0_359'
}
```

Comment: use JDK, what is the problem after changing it? can you provide a stacktrace ?

Comment: Did your problem solve?